# Trying to Tally up totals in a method

Tags: c#, winforms, sum

I am trying to tally up totals in a method called `playerTallyTotals` that comes from two different buttons. But instead of tallying them up and printing it out it just prints out the value of the second int passed to it.

```
private void playerTallyTotals(int playerCardTotalx)
{
     int playerCardFinalTotal = 0;
     playerCardFinalTotal = playerCardFinalTotal + playerCardTotalx;

     textBox1.Text = playerCardFinalTotal.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This method will always be the playerCardTotalx because the final total is a variable in the scope of this method only which is always reset to 0. You need to move the overall total outside of the method to be a member/class level variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `playerCardFinalTotal` outside of the method.  Its getting reinitialized (zeroed out) every time the method is called.  When outside of the scope of the method, `playerCardFinalTotal` will live for the life of the class (or form in your case).

```
int playerCardFinalTotal = 0;

private void playerTallyTotals(int playerCardTotalx)
{
    playerCardFinalTotal = playerCardFinalTotal + playerCardTotalx;

    textBox1.Text = playerCardFinalTotal.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int playerCardFinalTotal = 0;
playerCardFinalTotal = playerCardFinalTotal + playerCardTotalx;
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
playerCardFinalTotal = 0 + playerCardTotalx;
```

Or

```
playerCardFinalTotal = playerCardTotalx;
```

> But instead of tallying them up and printing it out it just prints out the value of the second int passed to it.

There is only 1 parameter passed to this function.  It sounds as though you logic itself is a bit flawed.

Perhaps you should have this type of logic:

```
private void playerTallyTotals(int playerCardTotalx, int playerCardTotaly)
{
    playerCardFinalTotal = playerCardTotaly + playerCardTotalx;

    textBox1.Text = playerCardFinalTotal.ToString();
}
```